# Google Chrome ignores capabilities

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to start chrome with some args, but they won't ty apply..., chrome starts with default window size and default position.

```
private WebDriver webDriver;
final ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=" + configuration.getUserDataDir(),"--window-size=0,0", "--window-position=-9999,0", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-gpu", "--disable-infobars", "--disable-notifications"  );
            webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Chrome log:

```
{
   "capabilities": {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
         "browserName": "chrome",
         "goog:chromeOptions": {
            "args": [ "--user-data-dir=C:\\ltb\\userdatadir\\", "--window-size=0,0", "--window-position=-9999,0", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-gpu", "--disable-infobars", "--disable-notifications" ],
            "extensions": [  ]
         }
      },
      "firstMatch": [ {
         "browserName": "chrome",
         "goog:chromeOptions": {
            "args": [ "--user-data-dir=C:\\ltb\\userdatadir\\", "--window-size=0,0", "--window-position=-9999,0", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-gpu", "--disable-infobars", "--disable-notifications" ],
            "extensions": [  ]
         }
      } ]
   },
   "desiredCapabilities": {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "goog:chromeOptions": {
         "args": [ "--user-data-dir=C:\\ltb\\userdatadir\\", "--window-size=0,0", "--window-position=-9999,0", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-gpu", "--disable-infobars", "--disable-notifications" ],
         "extensions": [  ]
      }
   }
}
```

Whole log : https://pastebin.com/PP5r4LrL

What im doing wrong?

selenium-java 3.13.0 chrome v59 chromedriver 2.30

Comment: Instead of `options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=" + configuration.getUserDataDir(),"--window-size=0,0", "--window-position=-9999,0", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-gpu", "--disable-infobars", "--disable-notifications"  );`  you can try : `options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
            options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");
            options.AddArgument("--disable-popup-blocking");
            options.AddArgument("--incognito");`

Comment: all set of compatibilities  can be found at https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/pref_names.cc

Comment: there is no methot called .addArgument();
only .addArguments(String... arguments) and .addArguments(List<String> arguments)

Comment: there is no :)) https://imgur.com/a/1bc3GyM

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the `.addArguments()` method so I can't attest to why it's not working.

Here is the method I use:

```
Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
ArrayList<String> args = new ArrayList<String>();
args.add("enable-automation");
args.add("test-type=browser");
args.add("disable-plugins");
args.add("disable-infobars");
args.add("window-size=1920x1080");
options.put("args", args);

capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

Also posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48100035/629186) with a link on how to also load extensions at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks it has issues with user-data-dir. I tried removing user-data-directory and it worked fine with changed window size:

```
options.addArguments("--window-size=10,10", "--window-position=-9999,0", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-gpu", "--disable-infobars", "--disable-notifications");
```

May be you can check with `/` instead of `\\` in user data directory. another possibility is it may load/overrides settings from profile in user data directory you provided.